# Mule: until-successful not taking variable number (mule expression)

Tags: java, mule

I have an until-successful scope containing an sftp endpoint. I also have a global variable called #[processingRetry] which contains an int (it could be 4, 5, ..)

When I add #[processingRetry] as my until-successful maxRetries value. I get an error:
NumberFormatException: For input string: "[processingRetry]"

If I place a value such as 5 directly, it works. Is there to use a custom variable for maxRetries?

Thanks,

Comment: it looks as if #[processingRetry] isn't evaluated to an int, or evaluated at all for that matter... but instead taken as is.

Comment: Looking at the source code of UntilSuccessful.java, it looks like the setMaxRetries method expects an int. Any plan to allow for an expression instead?

Comment: It does support spring property placeholders, if that's any help ${myprop.processingRetry} so you can store that variable in a properties file. Does this really need to be variable at runtime?

Comment: I basically want a simple synchronous retry after a few seconds of wait. The payload contains information on the maxRetries and seconds between retries. I have a default catch strategy that catches the outbound endpoint when there's no until-successful. Is there another way I could achieve a synchronous "retry" for sftp, http outbound endpoints? I'm not attached to until-successful in particular.

Comment: If my catch strategy could somehow retry the component/endpoint that threw the exception. Then this could be a solution. However, I'm not sure how to get back to the element that threw an error from the  default exception.

Comment: @RyanCarter: One question regarding your answer. If I were to set up a property using <set-property propertyName="processingRetry" value="#[processingRetry]" />
How would I go with then using the ${} notation to get a hold of it?
${processingRetry} or ${outbound.processingRetry} doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: set-property is for setting an outbound property on the message. THis would be available via #[inboundProperties.processingStrategy] but again this is a MEL expression so will not be available to configure. The only way really is via a spring or environment property via ${} but not at runtime.

Comment: Thanks :) I guess I'll just go ahead and write my own component that instantiate the SftpClient class instead of using the endpoint. I appreciate all your help clarifying this!